# CSS Animation Delay Not Working

Tags: css, css-animations

Trying to fade in one div....and 7 seconds later, fade another div in. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why it's not working. The animations themselves work (the fadein/fadeout animations) but I need the "going" div to fade in after a set amount of seconds. Anyone know how to do this correctly?

```
.coming{
    width:320px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size:24px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #222;
    padding:2px 20px;

    }

#people .coming{
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in;
}


.going{
    width:320px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size:24px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #222;
    padding:2px 20px;
}


#people .going{
    animation-delay: 7s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in;

}
```

Thank you. The fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the below for your `.going` class. The `forwards` in the animation property will make sure that the block doesn't go back to `opacity:0` (invisible) after the last key-frame is executed.

```
#people .going{
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards;
}
```

The above is short-hand for doing animation delay.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/35/)

Comment: Harry, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: What if animation is not supported by the browser. Opacity will still be applied to 0. Any work around?

Comment: @EtienneDupuis: You could do it like in [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/144/). This avoids the need for `opacity: 0` (note the change in `animation-fill-mode` from `forwards` to `both`). I don't have a browser which doesn't support animations, so can't test but I am fairly certain that it should work.

Comment: @Harry Exact! `animation-fill-mode` has to be set as `both`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

The problem was with both the order and the missing browser specific names:

Any specific properties need to be specified after the more general line otherwise they will be overridden.

You were also missing an initial `opacity: 0` on the going div (it was starting visible)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/9/)

Updated with `forwards` thanks to @Harry & @ VikasGhodke for pointing that out

```
#people .going{
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in forwards; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in forwards; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay: 7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
    -o-animation-delay: 7s;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}
```

You can avoid the whole specific style overwriting the shorthand settings issue by including the animation delay in the shorthand syntax like so:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/10/)

```
#people .going{
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in 7s forwards;
}
```

Comment: adding opacity:0 will make going class dissapear after animation

Comment: Hi dc5, thank you for your help. Your solution does work better than what I was trying, but as soon as the "going" div is faded in all the way, it completely disappears and I would like to have it stay on the screen. Any advice? I tried setting the opacity back to 1, but that didn't seem to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @IanProvidence Don't want to jump into dc5's answer, but you can try setting the mode to `forwards` as I have mentioned in my answer to overcome this.

Comment: Yes - see both @VikasGhodke 's comment and Harry's below - will update the fiddle and answer

Answer (score 1):

You are over riding a delay as soon as you set it.. so specify your delay after your animation.. but then one more problem arise .going will shown up first then after delay it will dissapear and then shows up which is not a good practice..

check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ee6jY/)**

```
#people .going{
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}
```

Another option is to play around timing and timing functions..

check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ4va/8/)**

```
.coming{
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Opera */
    animation: fadein 3s ease-in;
    }

.going{
    animation: fadein 10s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fadein 10s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 10s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 10s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
}
```