# keyframe fadein animation image disappears after animation

Tags: css, css-animations

The fadein animations works but after the 2second delay, and 2second animation it just disappears.  Also sometimes when I refresh the website the animation no longer works.

```
#frontPicture {

-moz-animation: fadein 2s 2s fade;
animation: fadein 2s 2s fade;
}

@keyframes fadein {
0%{opacity:0;}
100% { opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: Please check if setting the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265846/css-animation-delay-not-working/18266120#18266120) answer helps. (Note: That answer uses the shorthand property)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Animation property stays after animating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774829/css-animation-property-stays-after-animating)